# How to make static html page shrink or stretch to fit mobile screens?

Tags: responsive-design

Hello am using simple HTML (no responsive framework - very new to web development) and CSS. I want to make a page for mobile only screens. I am aware that there are responsive layouts and frameworks available, but at this point I do not want to use it.

Is there a way to "scale" (not re-arrange like in responsive design and flex box design) the HTML page to fit 100% of the screen. (no scroll, just 100% fits in the screen - more like an mobile app).

Answer (score 1):

If you:

- **avoid** explicitly setting the width of elements on the page, eg the width of an image or a div
- and you **don't** have a viewport meta tag in the head of your doc, eg `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
- and you **don't** have media queries in your CSS, eg `@media (max-width: 480px) {... }`

then smartphones will typically scale the page to fit the screen.

Good luck, hope this helps!